# How to work with two ipysheets at the same time. accesing cell atributes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to render two ipysheets in a particular notebook
as an example assume I have:

```
mysheet1 = ipysheet.sheet(rows=3, columns=4)
mysheet2 = ipysheet.sheet(rows=3, columns=4)
```

If I now do:

```
cell1 = ipysheet.cell(0, 0, 'Hello')
cell2 = ipysheet.cell(2, 0, 'World')
cell_value = ipysheet.cell(2,2, 42.)
```

the values are changed in sheet 2.
This is really weird. why is that that the last sheet created is modified?

why is following not working?

```
cell1 = mysheet1.cell(0, 0, 'Hello')
```

nor

```
mysheet1.cell(0, 0, 'Hello')
```

I would assume that since all is an object in pyhton ipysheet is also an object but it "cell" is not an atribute of mysheet1.

any plausible explanation?

This is actually extendable to column atributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, `cell` adds a new `Cell` widget to the **current Sheet** according to the [docs](https://ipysheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). One way that worked for me was to assign `Cell` to the attributes `cells` of the first sheet as a tuple. That is,

```
from ipysheet import sheet, current, cell, Cell

s1 = sheet(rows=3, columns=4)
s2 = sheet(rows=3, columns=4)

cell1 = cell(0, 0, 'Hello', )
cell2 = cell(2, 0, 'World', )

s1.cells = (Cell(column_end=0, column_start=0, row_end=1, row_start=1, type='text', value='Hello'), Cell(column_end=0, column_start=0, row_end=0, row_start=0, type='text', value='Hello'))
```

and one has [image]

but I think it is not a practical way to assign the cells like this, it would be easier if you first work with `s1` and then with `s2`.

Comment: I can not see then the way to render in voila several ipysheets in a practical way which data changes depending on other ipywidgets i.e. user interaction.

Comment: @Berlines yes all the changes the user makes goes to the `current()` sheet. So, it seems that there's currently no practical way to do it.